# Build a PHP page from snippets with NodeJS and JSDOM/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, node.js, jsdom

I am playing with creating a PHP page from ready code snippets and modify the page with JSDOM/jQuery. For example, I have this code:

```
window.$('title').text('<?php wp_title(); ?>');
```

But it inserts php tags escaped. How to make it put this string as it is without escaping?

I tried another library named [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) and code looking like this works just fine now:

```
$('title').html("<?php wp_title(); ?>");
```

No characters are being escaped and I can properly save this to a file.

**Update:** The reason why I am doing it is that I have to deal with WordPress themes creation and I want to streamline the process. As I am nor a big fan of PHP neither of WordPress themes structure, I want to build sets of files in Jade, run them through Express, then with an automated process compile them as a Wordpress theme. I have some success in doing this. Now I use Jade mixins to turn this:

```
+title
```

into something like this:

```
<title><?php wp_title(); ?>
```

in its simplest form.

So this way I can keep my templates easy to modify, nice and pleasant to work with.

Comment: Dom manipulation can't really cope with generating PHP - consider `<a <?php echo $attrs ?>>` or even something simple like `<p class="<?php echo $cls ?>">`.

Comment: Please explain the interaction between NodeJS and PHP

Comment: Basicly you're using the `.text` function on jQuery and that destroys all `<` and `>`, because those are HTML, you should try to use `.html`. tbh I think it's better if you just created a Jade Extension for this (if thats possible otherwise just fork the Jade engine)

Answer (score 2):

Use the html method if you don't want your content to be escaped

```
window.$('title').html('<?php wp_title(); ?>');
```

But be careful that your title doesn't contain a new line or a quote . That's why I prefer to use

```
// Using the version of wp_title that returns something instead of printing 
// directly to the output
window.$('title').html(<?php echo json_encode(wp_title('', true)); ?>);
```

Comment: Why no quotes around `<?php ?>` ? My IDE highlights it as a syntax error and doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, the second answer appears to be wrong. Unlike most javascript/php questions, in this one the JavaScript is generating the PHP, not the other way around!

Comment: @SergeyBasharov There are no quotes because that's what json_encode does for you, it generates a string that is valid in JS (if you pass it a string). It will output exactly the same thing as the first one, and like I said before, it won't break if `wp_title()` returns a string containing quotes or embedded newlines or other characters that need escaping

Comment: @Eric if the OP is trying to cause JS to run some PHP, both answers are wrong and there's no way to make it work. I was under the assumption that that is not what the OP wants to do, they just want to use the what's generated by PHP in their JS. Sergey, can you shed some light?