# How to create cms templates from HTML files via GruntJS?

Tags: wordpress, templates, code-generation, pug, gruntjs

In my webdesign process i use **jade, sass, coffe** etc. to generate static files via a **GruntJS** watch task into a dev folder. And most of the times after the build process is done, a cms comes along and want some templates to work. Thats usually html files with some php/ruby/python tags in it. Let´s say it´s a **Wordpress Theme**.

**The Problem is:**

1. i have to modify my generated files in the dev folder directly
2. when im modifing my source jade, html, coffee - files, the dev folder would be overwritten
3. if i clone the static files and move them into the theme folder, i have to apply manually every change i made to the src/dev folder to the cloned theme template files.

that´s very odd. So i´am in need of a grunt task that maybe...

1. generate the templates for me out of the static files (via a json mapping file)
2. generate the templates directly from the src files via special attributes, comments or something similar

[There´s just one thread i found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794177/build-a-php-page-from-snippets-with-nodejs-and-jsdom-jquery) where the user tries to accomplish the same with jsdom.
**Can someone help me to find a existing tool that accomplish such a task or do i have to build it on my own?**

Thanks, Robert

Answer (score 0):

Check out [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin)

> Replaces references to non-optimized scripts or stylesheets into a set of HTML files (or any templates/views)